# I am capitalizing the first letter of the first name and last name in hacker rank but getting syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin with a capital letter in their passports. For example, *alison heck* should be capitalized correctly as *Alison Heck*.

```
def solve(s):
    for i in s.split():
        s = s.replace(i,i.capitalize())
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    s = input()
    result = solve(s)
    fptr.write(result + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Can anyone explain this code? I am getting this error:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-2-dd917c231ace> in <module> 
      6 
      7 if name == 'main': 
----> 8 fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') 
      9 s = input() 
     10 result = solve(s) 
except KeyError: # raise KeyError with the original key value 
--> raise KeyError(key) from None 
     680 return self.decodevalue(value) 
     681 KeyError: 'OUTPUT_PATH'
```

Comment: On hackerrank, you can also erase the boilerplate code and just take input the way you want

Comment: I am not able to delete the by default code in hacker rank, is there anyway we can do it?

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide link to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running this locally. In that case, you need to set the `OUTPUT_PATH` environment variable.

To do this, in your console, run:

```
export OUTPUT_PATH=file.txt
```

and then run your code. Now, the output should go into a file called `file.txt`.

If you want this to persist between sessions, you can add the above line to your `~/.bashrc`, for example.

Comment: Yes I put the bracket, now I am not getting the syntax error but now I am getting another error, KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dd917c231ace> in <module>
      6 
      7 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 8     fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
      9     s = input()
     10     result = solve(s)

          except KeyError:
               # raise KeyError with the original key value
-->              raise KeyError(key) from None
    680         return self.decodevalue(value)
    681 

KeyError: 'OUTPUT_PATH'

Comment: @Bhavesh Please edit that into your question. like this -> I tried putting the braket, but now I am getting this error.. (your error)